# AngularJS 2 input field does not update ngModel for Jquery Date Picker date change

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, datepicker

I am having a problem with Jquery UI datepicker in angularjs 2 component.

It displaying changed date from date calender but its not updating underlying ngModel : dateSelected.

```
dateSelected: string = '';
```

Here the date picker input filed is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dateSelected" name='datepicker1' id='datepicker1' placeholder="Select a date"/>
```

And I am trying set the selected date from this.dateSelected model to second date picker which does not work.

```
$("#datepicker2").val(this.dateSelected);
```

On the other hand if I read selected date by JQuery val way it works fine.

```
  var selectedDateInPicker = $("#datepicker1").val();     
   $("#datepicker2").val(selectedDateInPicker);
```

Here is the code plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/iLAFa8yrCLeTcd27G8bY?p=preview

Can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Maybe you want to write custom directive that will implement `ControlValueAccessor`:

```
declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[datepicker]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,useExisting: 
    forwardRef(() => DatePickerDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DatePickerDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {  
    value: string;

    constructor(protected el: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        yearRange: "1:100", // you can pass it as @Input options  
        changeYear: true
      }).on('change', e => this.onModelChange(e.target.value));
    } 

    onModelChange: Function = () => {};

    onModelTouched: Function = () => {};

    writeValue(val: string) : void {
        this.value = val;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zXGFwRyOwhAocaxDM7Zy?p=preview)**

**Origin**

I think you can do it working by using the following:

```
$(selector-ng-datepicker).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  yearRange: "1:100",
  changeYear: true
}).on('change', e => this.dateSelected = e.target.value);
```

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yTmQKrJl4dQGnZ3oDyIo?p=preview)**

Comment: @ yurzui its a solution for one field, that can be handled in other ways (e.g. on blur ) but is there any generic solution in angular way or a standard solution.

Comment: angular way is don't use jquery. I added solution for multifield form

Comment: @ yurzui yes I understand angular way does not recommend using jquery, but some times in business need we have to add some existing working controls like jquery date picker, google map autocomplete these are not available yet in angular 2, so I have to use. Thanks