# Angular2: How to trigger ng-valid when jquery plugin is attached to ng-form object?

Tags: forms, validation, angular, jquery-plugins

I use the Angular2 ng-form and I like how it automatically figures out if all of the controls on the form are valid, and if so enables my form submit button.
However, if I use a cool jquery plugin on one of those controls, like datedropper in my example, then the form stays invalid until the underlying input control is valid.

Here is my form HTML:

```
    <form name="submitForm" #submitForm="ngForm">
      <div class="group">
        <input class="spring-date spring-input" data-large-mode="true" data-large-default="true" required readonly type="text" name="docdate" [(ngModel)]="docdate" #inputdocdate="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input class="spring-input" required type="text" name="company" [(ngModel)]="company" #inputcompany="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!submitForm.form.valid">SAVE</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is jquery to activate the datedropper (which I do in my TypeScript Component):

```
ngOnInit() {
        // Initialize Datedropper jquery select box
        $('.spring-date').dateDropper();
    });
```

Even if I update the duo-binded **docdate** value in my TS code within a datedropper jquery change event, the form doesn't figure out that it is valid until I start typing into the other textbox control.

```
$('.spring-date').on('change', (e: any) => {
            this.docdate = $(e.target).val();                
        });
```

**How can I use a jquery plugin (like datedropper or Select2) and after the user  changes the value, update the underlying input control in jquery and at the same time active the Angular2 form validation?**

My only other option is to abandon the built in Angular2 validation and write the code to validate all the controls manually. I feel like I'm missing an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case calling `onChange` inside angular zone will help you:

```
$('.spring-date').dateDropper().on('change', (e: any) => {
   // console.log(Zone.current.name); // prints <root>
   this.ngZone.run(() => {
     // console.log(Zone.current.name); // prints angular
     this.docdate = e.target.value;
   });
});
```

> How can I use a jquery plugin (like datedropper or Select2) and after
>   the user changes the value, update the underlying input control in
>   jquery and at the same time active the Angular2 form validation?

I would implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html) like:

```
export const DATE_DROPPER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateDropperValueAccessor),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: 'input.spring-date',
  providers: [DATE_DROPPER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateDropperValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef, private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(this._elementRef.nativeElement).dateDropper().on('change', (e: any) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.onChange(e.target.value));
    });
  }

  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lqmoyvJAb3bU97Huhj57?p=preview)**

See also

- [AngularJS 2 input field does not update ngModel for Jquery Date Picker date change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702721/angularjs-2-input-field-does-not-update-ngmodel-for-jquery-date-picker-date-chan)

Comment: The this.ngZone.run  fix worked like a charm!  For anybody else using this fix don't forget that you need to add:  import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';  and constructor(private ngzone: NgZone) to your constructor.  Thanks.